# If Target Is Strictly Within Range

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm working on a flat file database project where i have an aesthetic gap in the A column and a wingdings checkbox (chars "o", "þ") in the B column starting from b11 and down, defined as

```
range(range("b11"),range("b11").end(xldown))
```

so the way i've got it set up is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(Range("B11"), Range("B11").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each a In Selection
            If Not a.Rows.Hidden Then
                If IsEmpty(a) = False Then
                    If a.Value = "o" Then
                        a.Value = "þ"
                    Else
                        a.Value = "o"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next a
        Range("D4").Select 'really theres a lot more code everywhere but keeping it simple
    End If
End Sub
```

Summary: if it's checked, uncheck it and if it's unchecked, check it using wingding font.

So my question now is how to change the first IF statement so that it would only run when the target range is strictly within the range parameter given above. The current statement is "whenever any range selected crosses with the specified range do the following"

My goal is to have an IF statement that  "only if the selected range is within the specified range"

Thanx in advance

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So, is this question unrelated to Wingdings and checkboxes?   The question is about `IF` statements, correct It's a good idea to focus only on the issue at hand.  (See [mcve].)  Also, I will remove your tags that says `DO NOT USE FOR VBA`. Not sure if the 2nd image is related.

Comment: If you're only referring to single cells with `INTERSECT` then it is has to be "strictly within the range" to make a match.

Comment: correct it is a VBA question about if statements. I usually find providing a little extra info and backstory provides a better sense of understanding and allows others to duplicate my environment. sorry if i stressed too much on wingdings, didn't want people to get confused with checkboxes. I guess more related to my problem: I need a stricter if statement otherwise accidentally selecting entire rows could put it through a needless loop and crash the program. I'm really just trying to prevent this. and i cant be selecting one at a time when i got hundreds to select so selecting ranges it is.

Answer (score 0):

> only if the selected range is within the specified range

Here's one way to ensure your target range is completely within your given range, say, `B:B`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Union(Target, Me.Range("B:B")).Address = "$B:$B" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "In Range!"
End Sub
```

Comment: so this would be what I'd call "the boxing it in" method. adding additional canceling if statements to prevent left, right, above and below selections. I had this setup before; I'm currently vamping old code and now that I'm a bit better at VBA I'm trying to find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

So - not strictly what you asked for but there is an alternative solution where you check the font of the selected range to decide whether to process the cells.

(I've also altered the tick box value to better represent the matched pair - "¨" not "o")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Font.Name = "Wingdings" Then
        Dim C As Range
        For Each C In Target
            SwitchCell C
        Next C
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SwitchCell(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    If Target.Font.Name <> "Wingdings" Or Target.Rows.Hidden = True Then Exit Function

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target
        Case "¨": Target = "þ": Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Case "þ": Target = "¨": Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Case Default
    End Select

ExitFunction:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```